# Avoid shrinking grid columns inside flex

Tags: tailwind-css

I created a flex layout with a grid inside it using TailwindCSS ([Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/wPQS2plHkG)):

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">1</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">2</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">3</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">4</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">5</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">6</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">7</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">8</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">9</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">10</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">11</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">12</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The grid grows with the content until it hits the horizontal boundaries (page width):

[image: growing with content]

Then the content is shrinking like this:

[image: shrinked content]

How can I avoid this? I want it to y-overflow/scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `flex-shrink: 0` via the `shrink-0` utility class:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="shrink-0">
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">1</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shrink-0">
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">2</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shrink-0">
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">3</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shrink-0">
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">4</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shrink-0">
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">5</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shrink-0">
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">6</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shrink-0">
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">7</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shrink-0">
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">8</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shrink-0">
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">9</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shrink-0">
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">10</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shrink-0">
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">11</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shrink-0">
    <div class="border border-gray-300 text-center">12</div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-5">
      <div class="border border-gray-200">1</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">2</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">3</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">4</div>
      <div class="border border-gray-200">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```